# 'Starting Android ...' for over 60 mins

Tags: factory-reset

Following a factory reset after an Android problem, I started setting up my phone like it was a new one. Next day I was locked out of it for 24 hours, which I understand is a google protection system. Now I can login, but I get 'Android Starting ...'. This has been going on for over 60 minutes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping the cache partition. To do this, boot into the Android recovery menu. Make sure your phone is turned off and hold `Volume Up`+`Power` or `Volume Down`+`Power` for 5-15 seconds  until a screen appears with many options which displays  `Android Recovery Menu`. Now use the `Volume Down` button to go down, until you are at `Wipe Cache Partition` and then press `Power` button. This will remove any cache on the device, and make new cache, which  may will work to fix your issue. Now (re)boot your device and see if it has worked. I am not sure of this is gonna work for you, but you can try it.